# SBS as a RDP gateway

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-sbs

Hi all I want to start using my SBS:Essentials server as a RDP gateway but i'm getting cert errors saying can't connect becuase its an unverified certificate

Is there a cheap/Free way to issue a cert that will allow me to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a Certificate Authority in place within your environment no, you need to purchase an SSL certificate.  Any of the major retailers can do this from Verisign (expensive) to Thawte or GeoTrust.

As an alternative you can generate a self-signed certificate with IIS and install that certificate on everyone computer that will access your gateway.  This requires a lot of work on your part, most of which is worth the $50-100 for a year of SSL.

Answer (score 2):

If the machines that are connecting to the gateway are members of your domain or otherwise under your control, you can generate a certificate using AD Cert Services. Domain computers will automatically trust it. Non-domain computers will need to have it added to their certificate stores.

Otherwise, you will need to buy a certificate from a public certificate authority. And no, that's not going to be free.